# Ceph BucketNotifications do not push messages to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, ceph, radosgw

I have a `ceph` test cluster with three nodes with `radosgw` installed on the first node.
`ceph` version is `14.2.6` *(f0aa067ac7a02ee46ea48aa26c6e298b5ea272e9) nautilus (stable)*

```
# cat /etc/ceph/ceph.conf
[global]
fsid = a204e3b5-b0e1-4598-aadc-f46011b562f0

mon_initial_members = ceph-test-01, ceph-test-02, ceph-test-03
mon_host = 172.19.19.252,172.19.19.251,172.19.19.244

auth_cluster_required = cephx
auth_service_required = cephx
auth_client_required = cephx

public network = 172.19.19.0/24

rgw_frontends = beast port=80
```

And Apache Kafka broker for receiving messages.

I've created a topic according to the official `CEPH` docs:

(https://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/notifications/).

```
POST http://ceph-test-01/?Action=CreateTopic&Name=bucketnotifications&push-endpoint=kafka://kafka-test-01:9092 with S3 credentials
Response:
<CreateTopicResponse xmlns="https://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
    <CreateTopicResult>
        <TopicArn>arn:aws:sns:us::bucketnotifications</TopicArn>
    </CreateTopicResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>14804357-9c29-437d-9789-c127e1c13d23.44108.275</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</CreateTopicResponse>
```

I've created a bucket named `new-bucket` and checked its configuration:

```
GET http://ceph-test-01/new-bucket?notification
Response:
<NotificationConfiguration>
    <TopicConfiguration>
        <Id>bucketnotifications</Id>
        <Topic>arn:aws:sns:us::bucketnotifications</Topic>
        <Event>s3:ObjectCreated:*</Event>
        <Event>s3:ObjectRemoved:*</Event>
    </TopicConfiguration>
</NotificationConfiguration>
```

When I add or remove files to the bucket, `ceph` doesn't push notifications to the Apache Kafka topic. `Radosgw` logs (debug mode is on) contains the following strings:

```
2020-03-04 10:58:00.533 7f29a8da3700 20 notification: 'bucketnotifications' on topic: 'bucketnotifications' and bucket: 'new-bucket' (unique topic: 'bucketnotifications') apply to event of type: 's3:ObjectCreated:Put'
2020-03-04 10:58:00.533 7f29a8da3700  1 ERROR: failed to create push endpoint: kafka://kafka-test-01:9092 due to: pubsub endpoint configuration error: unknown schema in: kafka://kafka-test-01:9092
2020-03-04 10:58:00.533 7f29a8da3700  5 req 188 0.248s s3:put_obj WARNING: publishing notification failed, with error: -22
```

But Apache Kafka has no new topics created.

Comment: Remove `kafka://`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I guess `kafka://` is came from the CEPH docs, what is the reason to remove this prefix?

Comment: @Alex read the error `unknown schema in: kafka://`

Comment: @cricket_007 Ain't work with `kafka://` removed either, considering it as an `http` endpoint.

Comment: @Alex do you know if there's an open JIRA or github issue for this?

Comment: @cricket_007 as far as I'm concerned, there is no any related issue being opened, at least I haven't found any.

Comment: There is one more point to consider. We've looked at `rgw_pubsub_push.cc` https://github.com/ceph/ceph/blob/f6bd5699315c434ab7819646836df4c5181471ea/src/rgw/rgw_pubsub_push.cc source file and found out that there is a flag `WITH_RADOSGW_KAFKA_ENDPOINT` exists. The generated exception looks similar to the one in our case: `throw configuration_error("unknown schema in: " + endpoint);`. Is there a chance that we use a CEPH build with Kafka endpoints off?

Comment: @cricket_007 Here is the issue on the `CEPH` tracker: https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/44436

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a bug in nautilus releases that kafka schema won't check.
You can upgrade to version `15.2.0` that support this schema or wait for bug fix update on nautilus.